# How to capture two same id but different class in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

first of all, thank you for your time to read this question, and two things, I'm using ES5 and I don't use jQuery.

Right now I'm struggling a lot to figure what's the correct solution for the addEventListener, because for some reason it does not trigger for the second button which is only for the mobile screen dimensions, the problem is that the second button have the same id but different class, for example this:

```
 <div class="product-bg-container product-general-info variation-info">
  <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="Something-15892290" id="selected-option">

  {/* Desktop screen button */}
  <button id="buy-now" class="btn btn-lg hidden-sm-down btn-primary">
    Add to Cart
  </button>

  {/* Mobile screen button */}
  <button id="buy-now" class="btn btn-lg hidden-md-up btn-primary"> 
    Add to Cart 
  </button>
 </div>
```

Where I am trying to trigger the second button but it does not where I don't understand why it does, if the id is the same, should not matter, so I'm trying to figure how to trigger from the first button if it's clicked and also with the second if it's clicked, but I'm out of ideas...

```
var button = document.getElementById('buy-now');

if (!button) {
    return;
  }

button.addEventListener('click', function trackAddToCart() { 
  // more code for the event
}
```

I thought an idea to capture the attribute of the button, but it works in the first button but not for the second one:

```
var button = document.getElementById('buy-now');
var att = button.getAttribute('class');

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('class ' + att); //shows: class:    btn btn-lg hidden-sm-down btn-primary
        console.log('button class? '+ button); //shows:  button element: [object HTMLButtonElement]
      });
```

But when I click the second button... does not trigger or happening nothing, not sure why... and I can't change the `id` value (which it should be easy but I can't "company standard")

Can anyone help me to have an idea how to capture and trigger the event for the second button ??

Comment: Having duplicate IDs is **invalid HTML**. Fix that first.

Comment: If either one button is meant to be hidden, don't use two buttons. Use only one button and change the classes dynamically when you need.

Comment: Yes I thought the same, but I can't change the ID of the HTML... I tried to convince to my boss to change because it's invalid, but nope, I'll tell you the exact words that my boss told me "YOU SHOULDN'T CHANGE THE ID, NOT MATTER WHAT" so... I'm trying to figure other way.

Comment: this may create some problem for you in behaviour but meanwhile try to acess them by class instead of id

Comment: What's the point of having two buttons if  both are handled in the same way?

Comment: Guys I agree with all your comments, but (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻ my boss does not accept to change the id of the button not matter what, also I can't do the classic "querySelectorAll(.btn.hidden-xx-xxxx)" because there's a lot of buttons in other templates and I it shouldn't trigger for other buttons...

Comment: Can you add `onclick="handler(someid)"` to the `<button>`?

Comment: unfortunately no...

Comment: What? Even more same ids? Perhaps not, use `document.querySelectorAll('#id.class')` instead of pure class selector.

Comment: i think you should change your boss :P

Comment: How about using [nextSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp) ?

Comment: can you change anything about the markup? Like adding new Nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute *id* must be unique in a document. You can use [attributeStartsWith selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) or *class* with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then loop through all the button to attach the event (`click`) individually:

```js
//var button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.btn-primary');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=buy-now]');
button.forEach(function(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('class ' + this.classList);
      console.log('button class? '+ this.id);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="product-bg-container product-general-info variation-info">
  <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="Something-15892290" id="selected-option">

  <button id="buy-now" class="btn btn-lg hidden-sm-down btn-primary">
    Add to Cart
  </button>

  <button id="buy-now2" class="btn btn-lg hidden-md-up btn-primary"> 
    Add to Cart 
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought this, but the problem is that it should trigger only for the specific button for the buy (add to cart) and I know that the ID's should be unique, but omg my boss does not permit to change the value, that's the problem... and I thought with the querySelectorAll but there's other buttons with the same class in other pages... which is a problem to trigger the events... (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻

Comment: @MarcoMontoya, I have updated the answer with *Attribute Starts With Selector*...that should solve the issue......thanks

Answer (score 0):

`nextElementSibling` seems working in this case.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn");
var btn2 = btn1.nextElementSibling;
btn1.addEventListener("click",function(e){
console.log("btn1");
});
btn2.addEventListener("click",function(e){
console.log("btn2");
});
```

```html
<div>
<button id="btn" class="btn1">butotn 1</button>
<button id="btn" class="btn2">butotn 2</button>
</div>
```